# An example of non euclidean inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Please give me an example of non euclidean inner product.Is there any method to construct such an inner product?

Comment: What do you mean "non-euclidean"? Does the inner product on $L^2[0,1]$ given by $$(f,g) := \int_0^1 f\overline{g}$$ satisfy your criterion?

Comment: Um..... $2 \times $ Euclidean inner product? (What's a non euclidean inner product BTW?)

Comment: I have read that a real vector space together with a real inner product is called a Euclidean space and the corresponding inner product is called Euclidean inner product.

Comment: @souravchakraborty By this definition, any inner product over the real numbers is Euclidean.  But this is not a standard definition, as it includes infinite dimensional spaces like those in Prahlad's example.

Comment: From this definition I thought that any inner product which does not satisfy the conditions of real inner product will be non euclidean.But I found that the conditions of inner product and real inner product were same.So,if it is not a real inner product ,how can it be  an inner product?

Comment: Eucledian inner products use orthonormal basis to obtain the inner product like this:

$$U \cdot V = \sum u_i \cdot v_i.$$

Where the basis $e_i$ has the form $e_i = [0 \cdots 1 \cdots 0]$.

If the space is non-Eucledian, then $e_i$s are not orthonormal but must satisfy the inner product and linearity axioms.

e.g. for $\{U,V\} \in R^3$ we can have a non-eucledian product defined like this:

$$ U \cdot V = u_1v_1+2u_2v_2+3u_3v_3$$.

I'm not a mathematician so my notation and induction needs polishing.

Answer (score 3):

A Euclidean space is a pair $(V,g)$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space and $g$ is an inner product, if by "inner product" we mean a bilinear map $g \colon V \times V \to \mathbf{R}$ which is symmetric and positive definite.

However, in some contexts one doesn't have positive definiteness, say special relativity with Minkowski space $V \cong \mathbf{R}^4$ and
$$
g((t_1,x_1,y_1,z_1),(t_2,x_2,y_2,z_2)) = -t_1 t_2 + x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2 + z_1 z_2
,
$$
and some people still use the phrase "inner product" for this more general type of bilinear map. Someone who follows this convention might use the phrase "Euclidean inner product" to refer to the good old positive definite kind of inner product, and say "non-Euclidean" about something which is not positive definite.

If you consider complex vector spaces, you have a concept of inner product where the map isn't even bilinear, but linear in one factor and conjugate-linear in the other (but still positive definite). Perhaps the word "non-Euclidean" can be used in this context too, to distinguish it from the real case.

I haven't thought much about it, and I don't think it's worth making a big deal out of it, since it's usually clear from context what kind of inner product one is talking about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a symmetric matrix $A$ with determinant zero. A non-eucliden inner product can now be defined between two vectors $u,v$ by matrix multiplication  by $v^tAu$ (interpreting the resulting $1\times1$ matrix as a real number)

Comment: I don't think this is an inner product. Let $A$ be the zero matrix, or any symmetric matrix with a row of zeros. Then it is extremely easy to show that there are non zero vectors that satisfy $\langle \pmb{v},\pmb{v}\rangle = 0$.

Comment: It should be simply called symmetric bilinear form; $\langle v,v\rangle$ means that vector $v$  happens to lie in its orthogonal complement.

Comment: I don't understand. The question asks for examples of inner products and this example doesn't satisfy the definition of an inner product. In what way is this answer useful as an example of a non-euclidean inner product?

Comment: Perhaps we are having different definitions  of inner product.